# How to create a subpanel for a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

My lecturer wants me to use a sub-panel inside of a `JPanel` but he has not explained what that is and I can't find anything online that adequately explains what he is going on about.

Comment: A typical GUI might require a number of different layouts. Since each `JPanel` can use exactly one layout, this means combining panels within another 'parent' panel. Every panel but the parent one might be referred to as a sub-panel of the parent.

Comment: Here is a short, sample that demonstrates subpanels: [NestedPanels.java](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~tugrul/CS112/Code/NestedPanels.java)

Comment: *I can't find anything online that adequately explains what he is going on about* See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Panels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html). There are many working examples in the tutorial you can download and test.

Answer (score 0):

Subpanel of a `JPanel`  is just `JPanel` inside `JPanel`!
**`JPanel`** is a container in swing components, so it can contain other swing objects (Including a sub `JPanel`).